# Using Python with the Script Mediator in the WSO2 Tooling for the WSO2 EI 6.3.0

Tags: python, eclipse, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am currently trying to use a Python script in the Script Mediator of WSO2. I am using the tooling to deploy my APIs to my server (its a WSO2 EI 6.3.0).

Although it seems that Synapse supports using Python scripts, I cant found any source on how to use it.

This is what I have done:

- I downloaded the jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar and copied it to my ESB_HOME/components/plugins folder.
- I have a simple test.py script in my ESB_HOME/repository/scripts folder with the following code inside it:

  `def testFunction(mc):
      payload = mc.getPayloadXML()
      return mc.SetPayloadXML(payload)`
- My script mediator has the following configuration:

  `<script description="test" language="py" key="repository/scripts/test.py" function="testFunction"/>`

When I try to save the Sequence in which I use this Mediator, I get the error:

> Save failed
>   org.python.core.PyObject cannot be found by org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.esb.libraries_6.4.0.201809181248

Do you have any reference of configuration example working?